# Is it possible to create a Approval Link to the form?

Tags: workflow, infopath, approval

Is it possible to create a Approval Link to the form ?
Hi i tried everything to create a Approval link outside the e-mail(FORM_URN) but i dont find any solution for this. So my client want to approve the submitted form once he review it and he dont want to go back to email to click the link for approval because he think it has a lot of clicking. so here is my thought
- is it possible to create a button in infopath and create a link to Approval link ( same as the form_URN in sharepoint designer ) 
- is it possible to create a button via content editor that send the Approver to his current task?
Thanks

Below is the screenshot that i want to do. A button in the form that redirect the approver to his assigned task
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Click on three dots or hyperlink and make url in SharePoint workflow as shown bellow.
Basically, in the hyperlink editor add the following:

```
[%Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL%]/../EditForm.aspx?ID=[%Current Item:ID%].
```

Comment: i didnt catch you there my friend. So i will put that line in my sharepoint designer? any steps how to do it my friend? really appreciated!

Comment: ok i get your point now my friend. I will put that in email content right? i have done that before, but what i am trying to do is to create a approval link inside the submitted form or inside the browser when Approver opened the form so the approver dont need to go back to e-mail to click the approval link provided in the e-mail

Comment: Approver can approve from approval form (OOTB form) no need to again go to email right.

Comment: Hi i already updated my post my friend , please see screenshot below my post if you dont mind , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add link as shown bellow in screeshot:

[image]